# change itemsource binding property mvvm

Tags: mvvm, binding

I have problem on binding `ItemsSource` on `ListView` to a property.
I have bind my `ListView` to viewmodel property :

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding itemgrid, Source={StaticResource viewmodel}}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UCListFormat></local:UCListFormat>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I have 2 model ,

- 1 itemmodel
- 2 personmodel

I also have a menu that opens 1 view named 'form', but will generate `ListView` based on menu name.

For example:

menu person

- open 'form' and generate `ListView` with `ObservableCollection<person>`

menu item

- open 'form' and generate `ListView` with `ObservableCollection<item>`

on `ListView` I declare itemgrid as `ObservableCollection<object>`

Then I fill it with `itemgrid=ObservableCollection<person>` or if from menu item.
I fill the itemgrid with `itemgrid=ObservableCollection<item>`
base on property.

How can I do that? Because it's not working if itemgrid is
`ObservableCollection<object>`,

If I change `itemgrid=ObservableCollection<person>`, I can only display 1 at runtime.

on code behind I can do this like this

```
if (menu=="person")
{listview.itemsource=ObservableCollection<person>}
else
{listview.itemsource=ObservableCollection<item>}
```

on XAML I don't know how to do it

Comment: It is unclear as to what are you asking, can you some more code?

Comment: sory,can u look at this again.i give more detail about my problem...thx

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the explicit `ListView` `DataTemplate`, and declare DataTemplates in your resources somewhere to tell WPF how to display the various VMs

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Person}">
    <view:PersonView />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Item}">
    <view:ItemView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: sorry,i dont really get it. on datatemplate i plan to use itemtemplate selector for dynamically change column binding.
but i have problem on itemsource binding how it can accept 2 model